# Transformation between XML & Form -PHP

Tags: php, xml, forms

my code is working for a certain level of xml but my logic needs to get modified as i want it to work for everytype of xml file whatever element i add in the xml is readable and can  be edited . Please amend my code edit.php

This Code Is reading xml file Nd generating a form attached

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> INSERT VALUES OF THE GIVEN PHRASE IDS :</head>
<!-- <head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head> -->
<body>
<form name="form" action="edit.php" method="post">
    <?php

    $file = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" id="123" value="" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
           <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
XML;

    /**
     * @param SimpleXMLElement $node current node to process
     * @param int $level Depth in the XML tree
     * @param string $fieldPrefix
     */
    function makeNodeField(SimpleXMLElement $node, $level, $fieldPrefix = "")
    {
        // Indentation with the node level
        $indent = str_repeat("    ", $level);

        echo $indent, $node->getName(), PHP_EOL;echo "<br/>";

        $fieldName = $fieldPrefix;

        // If there's an ID on the node, display it and show a text field
        if (isset($node['id'])) {
            echo $indent, strval($node['id']), ' ';
            if (!empty($fieldPrefix)) {
                $fieldName .= '__';
            }
            $fieldName .= $node->getName() . '__' . strval($node['id']);
            printf('<input type="text" name="%s" value="%s" /><br/>', $fieldName, strval($node['value']));echo "<br/>";
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($node as $childNode) {
            // put a prefix in the children field name to get a valid field name for POST
            $childPrefix = $fieldName;

            if (!empty($fieldPrefix)) {
                $childPrefix = $fieldName . '__' . $count++;
            }
            makeNodeField($childNode, $level + 1, $childPrefix);
        }

    }

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

    makeNodeField($xml, 0);

    ?>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

it creates a form like this (attached snapshot)
[image: Form generated by this code]

```
edit.php ()

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     function printxml ($array)
     {

                    $xml = new DOMDocument();
                    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
                    $xml->formatOutput = true;
                    $last_index_ids = array();
                    $i_id=1;
               foreach ($array as $key => $value)
                     {
                        $key = $key;
                        $attrvalue= $value;

    //split unique input field names
                        if ($array[$key] == "" || ctype_space($array[$key]) ) {
                            $array[$key] = null;
        }
                         $expkey = explode("__", $key);

                          echo "<br/>";
    //ids of phrase                      
                         array_push($last_index_ids,end($expkey));
                         echo "<pre>";print_r($expkey);echo "</pre>";
                          $first_key =($expkey[0]);
    //first root element

    if ($xml->getElementsByTagName($first_key)->length == 0 && $first_key!='submit') {
                   $xml_element = $xml-> createElement($first_key,"");
                          $xml->appendChild($xml_element);
    }


                          foreach($expkey as $key=>$value) {

                          if(is_numeric($value)) {
                          $secondtag = $expkey[$key+1];
    //secondtag
                          $xml_tag = $xml->createElement($secondtag,"");
    //attributes                    
                          $domAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('id');
                          $domAttribute->value = $last_index_ids[$i_id];
                          $domAttribute1 = $xml->createAttribute('value');
                          $domAttribute1->value = $attrvalue ;
                          $xml_tag->appendChild($domAttribute);
                          $xml_tag->appendChild($domAttribute1);

                          $xml_element->appendChild($xml_tag);
                          $i_id++;
                                   }  

                                       }


            }

    $xml->save("rozeena.xml");
    }
    printxml($_POST);

    }exit();
    ?>
```

now this edit.php is working for this xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <gs-shop date="2015/4/23" version="10.0.3" id="gs" name="Garments_Shop">
        <catalog>

                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>

    </catalog>
    </gs-shop>
how to modify this so it can work for this 

<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" id="123" value="" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="blue"/>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="blue"/>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
           <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Blue"/>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="blue"/>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>



   and whatever i add to xml.
```

for Reference Example :
http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/index.html

Comment: @vipul sharma Can u help ?

Comment: @Sourabh Can u help ?

Comment: @scollado Can u help ?

Comment: @Drakes Hi Can u help ?

Comment: @Padawan00123 Hi Can u help ?

Comment: @b0s3 Hi Can u help ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Notice` message already says it: `fieldName` is not defined. This means, you use `fieldName`, but you haven't defined it. You must assign a value first.

Depending on the field you want to process, this must be one of the values shown in the output, e.g.

- `product_123`
- `product_123_0_0_color_swatch_color`
- `product_123_0_1_color_swatch_color`
- `product_123_1_0_color_swatch_color`
- `product_123_1_1_color_swatch_color`

---

To restore the XML from the input fields, you must parse and split the index values from the `$_POST` variable. Although from what you have shown, this is not possible, because `<product description="...">`, `<catalog_item gender="...">` or `<size description="...">` is missing, for example.

Comment: so what should i give in the fieldName . I explained what i am trying to do . All i want is to print the very same XML but with updated values whatever i give in input fields. I am a beginner kindly help me with it . I am not getting how to implement . Thank you

Comment: from all these attributes I only want Id and Value . Ignore gender , description. I have to change the Value of respective Ids